# Making a REST API: How do I route a filepath using express for node

Tags: api, node.js, rest, routes, express

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.get('/files/:service/:op/:file', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params.file)
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Calling `http://localhost:3000/files/farm/get/chicken` will log `chicken`. 
Calling `http://localhost:3000/files/farm/get/barn/yard/chicken` will log `barn`.

How can I make an Express `app.VERB(path, callback)` `path` log `barn/yard/chicken`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your route to something like this:

```
app.get('/files/:service/:op/*', function(req, res){
  console.dir(req.params);
  console.log(req.params[0]); // this is what you want
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end('OK');

});
```

Notice how the last parameter was changed to an * so that it takes single values (like chicken) or multi-values (like barn/yard/chicken). The issue here is that the slash character is used to split the URL components but you want to sometimes split the values but not others. The * will automatically lump the last set of values (1 or many) into a single element.

See http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params

Comment: Perfect. I'm not quite clear why the path is the zeroth parameter, but it works. (I would assume that the order would be `[service,op,path]` - it's not)

Comment: Not sure either, but it's probably because the named parameters :service and :op have been mapped to properties inside the req.params object. For example you can access them via req.params.service and req.params.op

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log(req.params.service + "/" + req.params.op + "/" + req.params.file);
```